# iPhone 5 no longer responding to touch

Tags: iphone, touchscreen

My iPhone 5 touchscreen is not responding to touch! Last night, my phone was working just fine. I plugged it in overnight to charge, and when I checked my phone this morning, the touchscreen had broken.

Here's what's going wrong now:

- The touchscreen isn't responding (I can't slide to unlock), though the screen *is* on.
- There are a bunch of lines on the screen, which disappear after the phone stays on for a few seconds or when I click the sleep/wake button.

The power button and home button are working as they should, I just can't get past the lock screen because I can't swipe to unlock (it's not registering the swipe or any taps).

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Try restarting your iPhone. Also, please clear up your language, we can't understand you! Comment back with `@JohnRamos` if that doesn't fix it.

Comment: (Ok, I edited the question)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend bringing the phone into your local Apple Store or using [the official Apple repair site](https://support.apple.com/iphone/repair/screen-damage) to send it in.

Sometimes, even when there is no obvious cause for screen damage, it can still happen somehow. This happened to a previous phone that I owned, I sent it in and the screen was replaced, fixing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

None responsive touch coupled with visual lines on the visual display is indicative of a damaged lcd screen.

This can happen in numerous ways, but ultimately end up in a screen replacement which usually solves the issue 99% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

My iphone 5s touch screen stopped working. It did work again after a while for like 5h and then stopped for good.

I decided to put it in a ziplock bag, get a bit of the air out and then I put it in the freezer for about 1-2h. Before I put it in the freezer the battery was at 7% then when I took it out 1% and it shut down.

I had it on charge for 1h but it didn't want to open at all so I took it out and left it till I woke up in the morning. I opened it , it was at about 47% battery and the touch screen was working and it still works (3rd day).